# Spring Boot Maven multi module project throw Duplicate Mapping Exception

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot, multi-module

I am trying to create a maven multimodule, spring boot application. The application runs in eclipse. but I build and run the  fat jar I get Duplicate Mapping Exception

I am planning to have multimodule like

Parent project

- System module
- Feature 1 module
- Feature 2 module
- web application module

My parent pom

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>org.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        <packaging>pom</packaging>    
        <parent>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.9.RELEASE</version>    
        </parent>
        <properties>
            <java.version>1.8</java.version>
            <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
            <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>           
        </properties>
        <modules>
            <module>system</module>
            <module>Feature 1 module</module>
            <module>Feature 2 module</module>
            <module>application</module>
        </modules>
```

System Module POM

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <artifactId>system</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>      
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>          
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-facebook</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-twitter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-social-linkedin</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0.M1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-social-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>util</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-beanutils</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-beanutils</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>       
    </repositories>
```

Application Module POM (web app)

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>    
    <artifactId>application</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.company</groupId>
        <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    </properties>    
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.company</groupId>
            <artifactId>system</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf.extras</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4</artifactId>
        </dependency>            
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlserver-jdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>${sqljdbc4.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.querydsl</groupId>
            <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.mobile</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-mobile-device</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
            <version>3.11</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.ulisesbocchio</groupId>
            <artifactId>jasypt-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <version>1.14</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Milestone Repository</name>
            <url>http://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <name>Nexus Repository</name>
            <url>http://nexus.mycompany.com/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.mysema.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>apt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>process</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>                             
                            <outputDirectory>target/generated-sources/dsl/</outputDirectory><processor>com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor</processor>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Now all this is created as flat project in eclipse and I am able to run application module as java application and is  works with out any issue.
 I build/install the project and take a generated application war and run it from cmd as java -jar app.war  I get the below error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManager
Factory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaA
utoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.Duplicat
eMappingException: Duplicate query mapping sy.getUsersByUpdatedDate
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBea
n(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(
AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(Ab
stractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFact
ory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(Defaul
tSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactor
y.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.
java:197)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplication
Context.java:1080)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitializa
tion(AbstractApplicationContext.java:857)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplication
Context.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWe
bApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107)
        at org.company.Application.main(Application.java:61)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.WarLauncher.main(WarLauncher.java:59)
Caused by: org.hibernate.DuplicateMappingException: Duplicate query mapping sy.getUsersByUpdatedDate
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.checkQueryName(InFlightMetadataC
ollectorImpl.java:555)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.applyNamedNativeQuery(InFlightMe
tadataCollectorImpl.java:595)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.addDefaultNamedNativeQuery(InFli
ghtMetadataCollectorImpl.java:601)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.QueryBinder.bindNativeQuery(QueryBinder.java:132)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.AnnotationBinder.bindDefaults(AnnotationBinder.java:240)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.source.internal.annotations.AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl
.prepare(AnnotationMetadataSourceProcessorImpl.java:184)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess$1.prepare(MetadataBuildingPro
cess.java:156)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProc
ess.java:253)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFact
oryBuilderImpl.java:847)
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactory
BuilderImpl.java:874)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEn
tityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:60)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManag
erFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFacto
ry(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:382)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEn
tityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(Loca
lContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMet
hods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBea
n(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
        ... 24 common frames omitted
```

[image: application-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
Above image is when I look into the generated WAR . I see 2 WEB-INF folder, though one says size zero.
But I am not sure why this expection.
I do have some sql queries in orm.xml in application module resource met-inf folder.

Comment: table name?  I had all this  working as a single spring boot project. I am trying to split it into feature wise module and that is also working in eclipse. But not working  when I  execute the final war

Comment: due to your exception you mapped getUsersByUpdatedDate query more than one, and it cause the exception.

Comment: I think I understand what the error means But I don't see it mapped more than once and how to fix it.

Comment: you can search you modules for getUsersByUpdatedDate

Comment: if I package as jar  I don't get this error. It happens only when I package as war

Comment: spring-boot-starter-data-jpa dependency is two times in pom file.